# Setting "istabstop = false" for the Icon on MahApps Metro theme

Tags: c#, wpf, icons, mahapps.metro

I recently added the Metro theme from MahApps into a wpf app I have, but now the application icon on the top left of my window is set as a tab stop and I don't want it to be.  I've looked all over the interwebs for a solution, but to no avail.

Using Snoop I found that the Icon is a ContentControl named "PART_Icon" but as far as I can tell there is no way to access it's attributes.

I've thought about just taking a fork from the MahApps.Metro source code and changing the attributes and then making a new .dll, but I'd rather find a less involved solution.

Thoughts?

Comment: feel free to fork the source, create a branch, make the changes (e.g. removing the focus) and then make a pr to the original source...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  There's no need to fork the source.  I had a couple other issues with the Metro Theme messing with controls so I just manually set their styles in the Resource Dictionary.  Just add this code into the Application xaml inside the "ResourceDictionary" tag.

```
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
```

The focus would also switch to a "FlyoutsControl" so I set IsTabStop in that one to False also:

```
        <Style TargetType="controls:FlyoutsControl">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
```

Lastly, for reference sake, we had a problem where the Textboxes were being given a MinWidth and MinHeight that were too big for our needs, so here is how you set them:

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0" />
        </Style>
```

One thing to keep in mind is that this will set these values for ALL controls of these types, so you'll want to make sure this doesn't mess you up anywhere else.  There ya go! Good luck!